# The continuity of a linear map varies according to the norm

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I'm doing an exercise about linear maps between normed vector spaces.

> [image]

Could you please verify if my proof on (1) looks fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Thank you so much ^o^

---

**My attempt:**

We have $\phi: \mathbb R[X] \to \mathbb R, \quad P \to P(1)$. It is easy to verify that $\phi$ is a linear map.

1.

Let $P_n = \sum_{k=0}^n X^k$. Then $\|P_n\|_\infty = \sup_{0 \le k \le n} (1) = 1$ and $|\phi(P_n)| = n+1$. As such, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{|\phi(P_n)|}{\|P_n\|_\infty} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n+1}{1} = +\infty$$

Hence $$\|\phi\| = \sup_{P \in \mathbb R[X]}\dfrac{|\phi(P)|}{\|P\|_\infty}= +\infty$$ and thus $\phi$ is not continuous.

2.

Let $P = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k X^k \in \mathbb R[X]$. It follows that $$\dfrac{|\phi(P)|}{\|P\|_1} =  \dfrac{|\sum_{k=0}^n a_k|}{\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|} \le  \dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|}{\sum_{k=0}^n |a_k|} =1$$

As such, $$\|\phi\| = \sup_{P \in \mathbb R[X]}\dfrac{|\phi(P)|}{\|P\|_1} \le 1$$ and thus $\phi$ is continuous.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Many thanks for your verification @JoséCarlosSantos ;) Now I can take a sleep ^^

Comment: @MadnessForMATH Your proofs are correct. I am wondering, has your teacher introduced the theorem that for linear maps between normed spaces "continuous" is equivalent to "bounded" yet? I wonder why you explicitly compute the operator norm of $\phi$ each time - for instance the first line of your proof of 1 already shows by a direct example that $\phi$ is unbounded.

Comment: Hi @RobertFurber, I was taught about that theorem too. Because the norm of $\mathbb R[X]$ is changed in (2), so I compute it a gain.

Comment: @MadnessForMATH I wasn't referring to that norm, but to why you compute $\| \phi \|$ at all in part 1. From the first sentence it already follows that $\phi$ is unbounded, and therefore discontinuous. Of course, this is not a mistake, and I thought maybe your teacher wanted this extra information every time.

Comment: Also, where did this question come from? There are English language mistakes - it should say "Let $E$ **be** the space of polynom**ials** ...".

Comment: I'm studying in France @RobertFurber :))